# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib' when I use blaze module

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have below environment

```
Linux "16.04"
Python 3.6.11
conda 4.8(latest)
```

I've two dependencies in my project

```
- blaze=0.11.3=py36_0
- pandas=1.0.5=py36h0573a6f_0
```

While resolving conda and pip dependencies, it is throwing below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'tslib'
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/my_env/bin/my_project", line 6, in <module>
    from my_project.cli import main
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_project/src/my_project/cli.py", line 3, in <module>
    from my_project.dbi import DatabaseConfig, DatabaseType
  File "/home/ubuntu/my_project/src/my_project/dbi.py", line 3, in <module>
    import blaze as bz
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/blaze/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from odo import odo, convert, append, drop, resource
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odo/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .backends.pandas import pd
  File "/home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odo/backends/pandas.py", line 94, in <module>
    @convert.register((pd.Timestamp, pd.Timedelta), (pd.tslib.NaTType, type(None)))
```

It looks like blaze is failing to get proper pandas version. So I tried to upgrade blaze(so that it'll auto download nested latest version of pandas), but I found that there are no updates for the blaze library.
https://github.com/blaze/blaze/tags

Also I see that 0.11.3 version is compatible with conda latest version,
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_linux-64/

Please let me know what is the best solution to resolve this...

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution on [github](https://github.com/blaze/odo/issues/621#issuecomment-485161314).

There are problem with `pandas.py` file inside odo package. So in Ubuntu you need to go to `Computer/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/odo/backends/` and open `pandas.py`. Than in line 94, change

```
pd.tslib.NaTType
```

to

```
type(pd.NaT)
```

Comment: Ouch. This should be resolved by blaze rather than monkey patching your pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with odo which has a blaze dependence, I installed the github package and it was fine. Try installing the GitHub version of blaze and see if it works.

Comment: I tried to install blaze from their latest GitHub package and unfortunately the same problem still exists.

Comment: I am having this problem too, and it's driving me nuts, because I am pretty sure odo is going to change my life :-)